# Deleting Image from revision history or a version of revision history

Tags: discussion, support, images, revision-history

How to delete an **image** from the **revision history** so that it is not visible to the future users? In case I mistakenly posted an image containing vital information and I changed that image later, the user's can still see the previous image in revision history.

How to I delete that particular version of revision history or that image from revision history?